# cookies session and security

Tags: php, session, cookies, encryption

I have a web app in which after user is logged in, he/she has cookie set for username set by `setcookie()`.

Please suggest better approach for security.

Comment: Use `session` instead of `cookie`

Comment: You mean you were detecting a logged-in user by a username *in* a cookie stored somewhere else other than "safe" on your server? Or you are using cookies for sessions and saving the username in a session identified by the session in the cookie?

Comment: dont use cookie for authentication ,use session it will auto set cookie

Comment: after user is logged in cookie is set for that username and then  $user = $_COOKIE['username'] is used to track so i think logged in user is detected in cookie outside server :(

Comment: If you re-inflate or re-initiate a session based on whatever was given to you in the request, what is *in* the request can be hazardous. They could, in an over-simplified example, get an account, login to your site, get the cookie, manipulate it's  username value, and suddenly they're logged in as *you*, an admin. This has happened. Don't be snowed by the "sessions are better than cookies", in terms of an exploitable concern, *they're both cookies*. It's what they could do, and in that sense session stored in cookies are unreasonably risky in many situations.

Comment: And take a look to your right. There's, uh, thirty or so questions hand-wringing over this issue. Don't micro-focus on this issue only, there's a whole lot of issues you need to be prepared to mitigate and control, like CSRF, XSRF and XSS, which are really challenging. Model your response on the actual hazard and how an attacker could use it against you. The latter is the exposure, not the "cookie vs. server" storage problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use PHP sessions instead of cookies. The session variables are server-side. PHP will automatically handle the session management. You can also overload its functionality if you want more control.

http://php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['user'] = 'michael'
```

With PHP-sessions, only a session identifier is stored in the browser cookies. You can store any information in the superglobal variable `$_SESSION`, and the browser will not be able to see or tamper with these variables.

For extra safety, you should store the remote address that was used to login, and compare it on each page load. This is to make sure that nobody hijacked the session id and is pretending to be logged in from another location.

```
session_start();

if (_logging_in__) {
   $_SESSION['user'] = 'michael'
   $_SESSION['ip'] = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}
```

To see if a user is logged in.

```
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
   // the user is logged in
   if ($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] != $_SESSION['ip']) {
      // the session id was hijacked so log out
      session_destroy();
      exit;
   }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really get to the root of the concern; session fixation is all too easy in many cases, so what does it *matter*? Both are "evil". Right?

Comment: [Session fixation](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html), open unsecured wifi networks, [Firesheep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firesheep) and wireshark, a proliferation of devices and web-exposed services, bad security implementation or suffering from tunnel-vision. It's not "bad". But you're not quite getting the *one* improvement that matters. Some frameworks, in fact, store their session data *in a cookie on the browser*. So is it that cut and dry?

Comment: You can't solve this problem without some type of session management. If you write your own code, or use PHP's built-in functionality doesn't matter. Hijacking can be stopped by taking a few simple precautions, such as verifying the remote ip like in the code above, and most importantly, using https with a valid signed ssl-certificate to prevent sniffing. If you know any other safe solutions, I'm happy to hear about it.

Comment: I'm sure there are lots of horrible custom solutions for session management out there. But just because some people don't know how to implement it correctly doesn't make it all unsafe. I don't get your point.

Comment: Forget about the exploit. My point is that sessions are really only marginally improving on what cookie-based sessions provide. It's not like you won't store *any* information in cookies. Here's what I'm getting at: It's a matter of what you can do with it. If the attacker, who has already exploited the system (and no approach is foolproof or entirely resistant, see RSA's non-repeating dongle nightmare), and has credentials, is it better or worse *if they may also dictate who the system **thinks they are***? This is why I don't like cookies storing usernames used to "remember " a user.

Comment: Nobody will be able to catch the session key and hijack the session by sniffing the network traffic if you use SSL. Unless they have access to the computer that runs the browser.